# Stuck in Skyview Temple?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm in the Skyview Temple, in the first three connected rooms—the middle room is the one that contains the map, the rooms to the left and right contain some Skulltulas and pink switches.

Unfortunately I raised the water level (twice) before I realized there was another pink switch in a hole or tunnel at floor level in the room to the right.

I don't have the Water Scale (or whatever it's called) yet, so I don't seem to be able to dive, but there also doesn't seem to be any way to lower the water back down (hitting any of the switches again has no effect).

So it would seem I don't have any choice but to start the game over from scratch.

Has anyone else encountered this situation?

Comment: Have you read [this thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/wii/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/answers/306852-flooded-water-in-the-skyview-temple) and [this one](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/switch/313531-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword-hd/answers/594830-i-made-the-water-level-rise-in-skyview-temple-before-hitting-the-crystals-in-the)? It seems like a similar scenario (I'm not familiar with the game, but can't image you have to restart a game to solve a puzzle that can that easily go wrong).

Answer (score 3):

Started my first playthrough November 2022 of SSHD. The issue is still there: if you activate the rightmost switch last you get stuck because the chamber (i.e. with the Skulltula and the chest at the head through which to access it) is already flooded.

- Newest patch installed
- Tried to leave the dungeon multiple times (also up into the sky) to reset the dungeon
- Tried to find a way to let Link dive
- Tried to find a way to drain the water
- Searched every inch for an alternative switch

After spending enough time with this problem I am confident the only solution is to reload another save slot or restart the game. Perhaps Nintendo has declared finding these solutions as part of the journey because the issue remains unresolved since the Wii version of the game.

Anyway, as a gamer, I've now accepted that you can get stuck in Zelda games.
The testing time is limited while the ambitions and the creativity of the devs is not.  So folks, better "save" than sorry.

P.S.: Took me exactly three hours to enter the dungeon again after restarting the game. Most of this time you have to watch cut scenes and click away text boxes. At least this time I had pumpkin soup, the 300 rupee extra purse and the bug net. Getting stuck was really part of the journey after all...

P.P.S.: It's worth mentioning that you *can* leave the dungeon because you only need the little key... that got me confused because they hid it a bit meanly. For some reason I assumed you have to flip all switches and the game had a bug. In fact, it works like intended. I think the TO had the same misunderstanding but never clarified it. Restarting the game wasn't really necessary.

Comment: Hi Andreas, just to clear things up: I misinterpreted the situation yesterday and thought the question here was written by you as well. My comments probably made no sense, and I apologize for that :)

Comment: Yes, I knew. Thank you for clearing that up. Not everybody does that!

Answer (score 1):

According to several walkthroughs -- which I had consulted in desperation -- you have to crawl into that hole/tunnel because one of the pink switches is there.

I am 99.9% sure I never did that.  I don't believe I even noticed the hole until after consulting the walkthroughs -- shame on me -- but at that point I had already raised the water level.

But as it turns out, I was able to move on.  The water was high enough that I could jump to the vines on the right wall in the middle room and climb up.  I thought I had tried this after raising the water level a 2nd time, but it's possible I didn't. (Or maybe I did but missed the vines because I was not pointed in quite the right direction.)

But I'm almost positive that I never crawled into that hole ... which would mean the walkthroughs are inaccurate on that point.

Comment: The walkthroughs should totally link to your thread, David.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to restart.  Sorry... it happened to me too, and there is no way to get the water to rise a second time if you did the first switch out of order.